# Is there any way to know when data is inserted and updated in Firebase database?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I have searched everywhere, but couldn't find any relevant information. Does firebase provide data insertion and update timestamp?

If so, how do I get it in JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you have to add these values yourself.

You can add a **creationDate** and an **updateDate** fields in each item.

Use the [firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.ServerValue#.TIMESTAMP) to set these values.

Example :

```
ref.child('ITEM_KEY').child('updateDate').set(firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
```